# Generating a random ratio

Tags: c++, math, random, poisson

I am reading a book and it has this function. I do not understand what is the usage of using `rand()/(RAND_MAX)`, doesn't it just produce a random ratio `value`? How can we use a random ratio `value` to check whether it is larger than the exponential?

```
#include <cmath>

bool isCustomerArrived(double arvTimeDiff)
{
    double value;

    value = static_cast<double> (rand()) / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX);

    return (value > exp(- 1.0/arvTimeDiff));
}
```

The explanation I have from the book is

To run the simulation, we need to know the number of customers arriving at a given time unit and how long it takes to serve the customer. We use the Poisson distribution from statistics, which says that the probability of y events occurring at a given time is given by the formula: [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=poisson%20distribution%20formula&sxsrf=ALeKk02accrJbjNUj2uV058uUvhkKzMDxA:1610187803742&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=4K4EjIl1lFH4BM%252C1Y9sFoXVilC3HM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTDg8f1ABQe9yV_jJa9IKUHVyx0kg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO48CA0Y7uAhXexjgGHQ7YBmwQ9QF6BAgYEAE&biw=1536&bih=722#imgrc=4K4EjIl1lFH4BM) in which λ is the expected value that y events occur at that time. Suppose that, on
average, a customer arrives every four minutes. During this four-minute period, the customer can arrive at any one of the four minutes. Assuming an equal likelihood of each of the four minutes, the expected value that a customer arrives in each of the four minutes is, therefore, 1/ 4 = 0.25. Next, we need to determine whether or not the customer actually arrives at a given minute.
Now, P(0)= e^ (- λ) is the probability that no event occurs at a given time. One of the basic assumptions of the Poisson distribution is that the probability of more than one outcome occurring in a short time interval is negligible. For simplicity, we assume that only one customer arrives at a given time unit. Thus, we use e^ (- λ) as the cutoff point to determine whether a customer arrives at a given time unit. Suppose that, on average, a customer arrives every four minutes. Then, λ = 0.25. We can use an algorithm to generate a number between 0 and 1. If the value of the number generated is more than e^ (- λ), we can assume that the customer arrived at a particular time unit. For example, suppose that *rNum* is a random number such that 0 ≤ *rNum* ≤ 1. If *rNum* is larger than  e^ (- λ), the customer arrived at the given time unit.

Comment: If you ask and answer by yourself just a few simple questions, you should be able to figure what this does all by yourself! Ok, try this: 1) Do you know what is the range of values that `rand()` returns, the smallest and the largest possible value? 2) what is `RAND_MAX`, what does tihs value mean? 3) if `rand()` returned `RAND_MAX`, what would the result of the division be? 4) if rand() returned half of what `RAND_MAX`, what would be the result then, quarter of `RAND_MAX`? Did you get it, yet?

Comment: Let me take a few minutes to understand this

Comment: To answer your question
1. rand() ranges between 0 to RAND_MAX
2. RAND_MAX means the upper limit of rand() which is a very large int
3. The result of division will be 1 (the probability)
4. 0.5, 0.25
I still don't get it, why do we need to use rand()

Comment: Well, `rand()` is the simplest mean to generate a random number. So, what you're saying is that dividing `rand()` by `RAND_MAX` means that you get a random value between 0 and 1 instead of 0 and RAND_MAX? So, what else is unclear to you?

Comment: Why do we use rand() which produce random number to check whether it is larger than the `exp(1.0/arvTimeDiff)`, how can we use a random ratio (`value`) to check whether it is larger than the exponential

Comment: Seems related to/use [Poisson_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: Yes, it is using Poisson distribution, but the key is why it can randomly use a random ratio to compare with Poisson distribution

Comment: That's something that should be directed to whoever wrote the entire program, as to the reason for doing that.

Comment: It's from a book, I wonder how can I ask the author XD

Answer (score 2):

Explanation:

1. `#include <cmath>`:  include the 'cmath' library for performing mathematical operations. [See reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/)
2. `bool isCustomerArrived(double arvTimeDiff) {`: declare a method that accepts a `double` value named `arvTimeDiff`, and return a boolean value(true or false). See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_booleans.asp) for more on booleans in C++.
3. `double value;`: declare a `double` variable named `value`.
4. `value = static_cast<double> (rand()) / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX);`: set the value of `value` to the division between a random number(using `rand()`, which returns a `int` type, thus we need to type cast to `double`) and the maximum the `rand()` function outputs, is `RAND_MAX`, so therefore the biggest the division can be is 1, and the smallest, 0. Since ratios are just fractions, this makes perfect sense why the author writes this line of code. [(See here for more)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/)
5. `return (value > exp(- 1.0/arvTimeDiff));`: return whether the value computed is bigger than `e^(-1/arvTimeDiff)`.
6. > How can we use a random ratio value to check whether it is larger than the exponential?

   I don't quite get what you mean... what is the purpose of the program?

**Edit**:

> Let say we are given 100 unit time, we have 1 server, and the server needs an average of 5 unit time to serve a customer but a customer arrives at the server on an average of 4 unit time

Given this information, we can assume the starting time is `t = 0`, and customers arrive quite randomly, but manage to come 25 times before `t = 100`. Given this, we know that customers are probably not going to every *perfectly* every 4 units in time. The method has the name `isCustomerArrived`, which means the method is going to return a boolean giving whether a customer has arrived. With this, I assume this method was created to *simulate* the flow of customers. The input parameter to the method is named `arvTimeDiff`, which means 'arrived time difference'. There are two implications/meanings of this variable name:

1. The method gets the time spacing between customer arrival times.
2. The method gets the time between the start of the server(`t = 0`) and the arrival of the customer according to it.

I plotted the value threshold of the boolean function [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ly2ucblzu4)(`e^(-1/arvTimeDiff)`).

Case 1 (from above): If you look at that graph, you notice that the function approaches 1 as the value of `arvTimeDiff` increases(along the x-axis). We can ignore the negative side(because, the server probably starts before customers arrive). This means, if the input to the method is too big, there isn't a customer(`isCustomerArrived` returns `false`). In this case, I think the book's author is trying to model an irregular customer demand because in the graph from 0 to 4 (they have a difference of roughly 4[average]), where customers arrive more regularly than every 4 units in time.

Case 2 (from above): This models a huge increase in customer demand in the (roughly) first two time units on the server's start. This can be seen because the threshold for the boolean method is very low, but increases drastically to ~1 when you reach `arvTimeDiff` = 10.

If this wasn't what you needed, perhaps could you quote a few passages in the book about the project?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, to your question, the purpose of the program is to do a simulation about a server serving a customer to buy a ticket. Let say we are given 100 unit time, we have 1 server, and the server needs an average of 5 unit time to serve a customer but a customer arrives at the server on an average of 4 unit time

Comment: @BeginnerA-Z Please add relevant information like this to the question, instead of in a comment underneath an answer.